# Do I need to worry about sequoia needles falling into my containers?

Tags: soil, cedar

I'm new to my house, and I have a half dozen containers just underneath a giant sequoia. I now see a small amount of the needles are falling into the containers. **Will the sequoia needles harm the plants in the containers? Should I remove the needles or move the containers?**

I can see nothing grows directly under the tree where there are lots of needles. And I've always heard cedar(-like) trees did *something* to the soil to prevent plants from growing. I've also read that while needles are acidic, [they break down in compost pretty quickly](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/54991/sequoia-needles-as-mulch-or-compost), but here they're falling directly into the containers not being composted. Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: what's growing in the containers?  Annuals, perennials, vegetables???

Comment: Kale, garlic bulbs, dwarf chamaecyparis, and a japanese maple.

Answer (score 2):

In permanently potted plants, you can remove the buildup if it becomes too great. It shouldn’t pose any threat in small amounts, or over the course of a single season.

Comment: Welcome back, J. Musser!